# adding a telerik dropdown/autocomplete control to telerik asp.net mvc grid

Tags: telerik-mvc

I have a telerik MVC grid wherein I want to add one databound column. I want this column to show telerik dropdown/autocomplete control.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just show the data it is easy - you define the DropDownList in the [Template](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/templatesclientside) method of the column.
If you want your changes to affect the model and change it - you need to use EditorTemplate. Use the UIHint attribute or use the TemplateName method of the column to specify the editor. You can check [this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/clientedittemplates) demo for such implementation.

Comment: Both link are deprecated!